# Parsing numbers in Javascript while keeping positive and negative numbers

Tags: javascript

I have values like:

```
 (GMT-06:00) Guatemala
 (GMT+11:00) Guadalcanal
```

I am parsing them like this:

```
var gmtoffset = selectedzone.match(/\d+/g);
```

It produces outputs like this:

```
["06", "00"]

["11", "00"]
```

How do I preserve the negative in the number during parsing such as for -06:00?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get a string containing also a `-` or `+`, you could try to add `[-+]?` before the digit matcher. This would search for digits, and if a `-` or a `+` are present, then adds them as well to the result.

To recap, the regex should be: `/[-+]?\d+/g`.

I hope I did not misunderstood your question or over simplified the answer.

Edit: I noticed you only mention the negative sign. If you are not interested in the `+` sign, you can get rid of it by modifying the regex like this: `/(-)?\d+/g`. This would only search for the `-` sign, and include it if present.

Comment: you don't need the pipe. it's just /[-+]?\d+/g